# Trying to categorize and condense data in R with a key word

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

```
df <- read.csv("https://query.data.world/s/gzjmftivszsy44ukfak2e7ksig35jm", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
library(ggplot2)
library(qqplotr)
library(stats)
library(dplyr)



coverage_by_Geography = data.frame(avgcancerdiag= df$avgAnnCount, county = df$Geography, PubCoverage = df$PctPublicCoverage, privcoverage = df$PctPrivateCoverage, deathrt = df$avgDeathsPerYear)
ggplot(data = coverage_by_Geography, aes(x = privcoverage, y = deathrt))+geom_col()
ggplot(data = coverage_by_Geography, aes(x = PubCoverage, y = deathrt))+geom_col()
```

I am trying to take a bunch of county's within a column, condense them into states and average their data out to state numbers instead of county. Am stumped on how to do it.

Comment: please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general `tidyverse` solution follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://query.data.world/s/gzjmftivszsy44ukfak2e7ksig35jm")

df %>%
  separate(Geography, c("county", "state"), ", ") %>% 
  select(state, county, everything()) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarize(across(-c(county), mean))
```

The code separates county and states into two columns. Grouping by state allows you to summarize the data. Here, I asked for the mean of all of the columns, but this probably doesn't make sense for all of the different data types. Hopefully this gets you closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: this was extremely helpful. Its more so the ability to take all the counties in one state and average the numbers out to give a state average, condensing the data